# Redirect http to https on Nginx not working

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a server running on DigitalOcean and have a domain name I've purchased.
My server has nginx running on it and I'm trying to get my http requests to redirect to https but nothing I've tried is working.
I know it should be really simple and I've looked at dozens of example but for some reason mine still isn't working.

Right now this is what I have

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    listen [::]:80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;   
}
server {
    # SSL configuration
    #
    listen 443 ssl;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl;

    root /var/www/example.com;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/keys/example.key;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/keys/example.com.chained.crt;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

}
```

Is there anything wrong with this or anything I should change?
My website works fine and has the lock icon in the browser indicating it is secure if I type in https://example.com or https://www.example.com

But if I just use example.com http://example.com or www.example.com it says the page can't be found.

Comment: Maybe your firewall rules block port 80?

Comment: Oh man that was it :(  Thank you!